# stripe react native subscription creation-Error- This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription paymentsheet in react native, below is my code for backend. When I uncomment trial_period_days: 3, then it works even if payment methods are not declared. But if I comment this line, then I am getting error - "StripeInvalidRequestError: This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method. Please consider adding a default payment method." I tried below code to declare payment methods, but it did not work. I want new customers to also be able to use all the available payment methods that their country and OS platform supports.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey);
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Test');
});
app.post('/payment-sheet-subscription', async (req, res) => {
  const {email = `test${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999) + 1}@domain.com`} =
    req.body;

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email});

  const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customer.id},
    {apiVersion: '2020-08-27'},
  );
  const PRICE_ID = 'price_1NQ4EnSBro6pGrG8ZYfdBX5x';
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{price: PRICE_ID}],
    // trial_period_days: 3,
  });
  const updatedSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
    subscription.id,
    {
      payment_settings: {
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
      },
    },
  );
  if (typeof updatedSubscription.pending_setup_intent === 'string') {
    const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.retrieve(
      updatedSubscription.pending_setup_intent,
    );

    // if (typeof subscription.pending_setup_intent === 'string') {
    //   const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.retrieve(
    //     subscription.pending_setup_intent,
    //   );

    return res.json({
      setupIntent: setupIntent.client_secret,
      ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
      customer: customer.id,
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      'Expected response type string, but received: ' +
        typeof subscription.pending_setup_intent,
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pending_setup_intent` is only applicable for non-payment scenarios, such as trials.

When creating a subscription that *does* require payment before you have a payment method set up for the customer, you'll want to use `payment_behavior='default_incomplete'`, as shown in Stripe's docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription). With this, you can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) the `latest_invoice.payment_intent` to get a `client_secret` to use in your front end app to complete the first payment. This is also shown in the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#collect-payment).

Comment: Seems like its only for web, react native part is missing.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit more? The concepts I described should apply regardless of platform choice.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it indeed helped. I was wrong in my 1st comment, it worked for react native as well.